# How can GPU's shared memory be used in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

Could someone tell in general how is GPU's shared memory used by the Matlab parallel computing toolbox. And can I use it explicitly to synchronize MPs units for example.

BTW. I have a GTX 580 which have 1.5GB of memory, 32 cores per MultiProcessor (16 cores per MP) and 64Kb of shared (L1) memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the answer for Matlab, but if you're willing to work in Python, then [PyCUDA](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda) is your friend. You develop kernel code directly in CUDA-C, written out in long strings in Python. Then PyCUDA allows you to compile these, set up device variables, send data to and from the device, and then execute your kernel with launch configurations to control threads/block, etc. To utilize shared member, you merely declare variables with the `shared` keyword in your CUDA-C code-as-Python-string.

I wrote some code for image processing which [is linked here](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~ely/faceparts/software.html). You can unpack it and see the way that I wrote the CUDA-C source modules as Python strings. With NumPy and SciPy, the rest of the user experience in Python is exceedingly similar to Matlab -- just better. If you're not married to doing this project in Matlab, consider switching it over to PyCUDA.

Comment: Also, I just thought this was a useful aside that was too large for a comment. Since I did not answer your Matlab question, I totally understand if you do not wish to up-vote or accept this as an answer.

Comment: The first time I read some Python code...Impressing how easy it is readable. I will give it a try as I have some free time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maiss,

I'd like to chime in on M-code for the GPU - I've found Jacket to be a useful alternative to access the GPU. Jacket uses shared memory by default to get things done, and it has an SDK if you wish to control things yourself.

The GTX 580 is a great card, but if you have the cash for it, I'd personally recommend some of the Tesla GPUs for their reliability over the long term (especially for long running scientific applications).

Comment: Thanks Vish, I will probably get one next year. Just need to convince my supervisor first!

Comment: Yes, the GTX cards are great for gaming ;) I have one myself. But it was after I burned a GTX with a long-running scientific computing application I learned the merits of a Tesla. Again, my personal experience - others might have a different opinion.